# Два запроса в одном

Tags: sql

Нужно посчитать общее количество строк в таблице и количество строк, удовлетворяющих условию. Можно ли это в целях экономии ресурсов как-то выполнить одним запросом, без UNION?

```
SELECT count(name) as c FROM mytable WHERE name = "abc"
UNION ALL
SELECT count(name) AS t FROM mytable
```

Comment: можно не использовать UNION, да. А какие ресурсы ты экономишь и почему думаешь, что при UNION происходят какие-то неимоверные траты?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я так понимаю, что здесь выполняется два независимых запроса, а UNION лишь объединяет их в один вывод. Оптимизировать это никак нельзя, правильно? Затраты, пусть имелочные, важны, поскольку в реальности дальше по условию идёт ещё 4 подзапроса, и всю эту кучу нужно повторять 800 раз (в каждой из БД) за минимальное время раз в сутки.

Comment: два запроса будут в любом случае, т.к. их ничто не объединяет.

Answer (score 1):

Обычное условное агрегирование.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(name = 'abc')
FROM table
```

В строгих СУБД `SUM(CASE WHEN name='abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.